# How to have GoLand constantly inspect all files like VS Code does

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

Does anyone know how to have GoLand constantly inspecting errors in code? Right now it inspects ONLY the open files and shows the status on the top-right corner like this:

[image: live inspection results for current open file]

But in VS Code, it constantly checks all errors of the working module.

[image: live inspection results of all files]

GoLand does offer manual inspection but it's not as efficient and often checks irrelevant modules too (when I set it current module then it can't detect any errors)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Goland issue GO-4618](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4618):

> They might be limiting the contents of the Problems tool window to just the current editor for performance and usability reasons.

[GO 9494](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-9494) is following the issue: "Customize Problems View reporting scope"

> There should be a way to customize the Problems View window to support the following scopes:
>
> - Current File
> - Current File's Package (I'd default to this)
> - All Opened Files Packages
> - Whole Project ([IDEA-68854](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68854))

Still in progress (oct. 2021) though.